# A RenderFlex overflowed by 1443 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make it scrollable...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMEVf.png) For some reason its not not scrolling and i tried adding singleChildScrollview still not working.... Pls look at the picture to understand better... so i posted the full code so that you guys can help me better... This was the error i got "Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView."

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:memoryblog/helper/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:memoryblog/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:memoryblog/services/database.dart';
import 'package:memoryblog/views/create_blog.dart';

class MemoryRoom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MemoryRoomState createState() => _MemoryRoomState();
}

class _MemoryRoomState extends State<MemoryRoom> {

  AuthMethod authMethod = new AuthMethod();

  DatabaseMethods databaseMethod = new DatabaseMethods();

  Stream blogsStream;

  Widget BlogsList(){
    return Container(
      child: blogsStream != null ?  Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: blogsStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return BlogsTile(
                      authorName: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['memoryName'],
                      title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'],
                      description: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['desc'],
                      imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['imgUrl'],
                    );
                  }
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      )  : Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    databaseMethod.getData().then((result){
      setState(() {
        blogsStream = result;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Memory"
            ),
            Text(
              "Blog",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              authMethod.signOut();
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Authenticate()
              ));
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Icon(Icons.power_settings_new)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: BlogsList(),
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CreateBlog()
                ));
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlogsTile extends StatelessWidget {

  String imgUrl, title, description, authorName;
  BlogsTile({@required this.imgUrl, @required this.title, @required this.description, @required this.authorName,});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
      height: 170,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: imgUrl,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 170,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black45.withOpacity(0.3),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  title,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4,),
                Text(
                    description,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4,),
                Text(authorName)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you indent your code?

Comment: Please have a look at how to ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you post the sample json.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView in place of the column. OR
Wrap Column with SingleChildScrollView

Comment: just did that... i used listView in place of column nothing i used singleChildScrollView nothing

Comment: include a repo link as far as my understanding ListView should work

Comment: how should i do that pls?

Comment: child: blogsStream != null ?  Column <== this should me made into listview you should upload your full code if not i cant help.

Comment: pls i dont understand

Comment: try changing all the rows and columns to ListView maybe and pass the direction property as needed otherwise I dont see any error. Same problem is happening with me my, code works fine in frield's pc but not in mine.

Comment: update dart flutter restart your IDE. You have two return statement under streambuilder and change to listview

Answer (score 0):

```
return Container(
child: blogsStream != null
    ? ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: blogsStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return BlogsTile(
                      authorName:
                          snapshot.data.documents[index].data['memoryName'],
                      title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'],
                      description:
                          snapshot.data.documents[index].data['desc'],
                      imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['imgUrl'],
                    );
                  });
            },
          )
        ],
      )
    : Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
```

);

Comment: honestly i did that and it didnt work.... pls i have posted the full code pls check it out